# How to count all characters including spaces and regex in php?

Tags: php, mysql, count, character

how can I count all characters? I am selecting a field from mysql (which is a plain text) and I would like to count all letters in that text that is extracted (including spaces and all special characters).

I am comparing the value with a number, for example:

If text has more than 1000 characters then `$var++`
so I know how many fields have more than 1000 characters.

`strlen` does not seems to be counting right.

Comment: [strlen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) / [mb_strlen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php) ? what do you mean _does not seems to be counting right_?

Comment: "Strlen does not seems to be counting right" - please elaborate. And/or take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_length

Comment: it is not counting the right number of chars. I tried to count chars from one field using strlen and then try to count this chars with online "count letter" application and the result was not the same.

Comment: I will try the suggested below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably happens because of encoding issues. This has nothing to do with `regex`s.

You can use `mb_strlen` to get the correct length.

Answer (score 5):

Use `strlen` or `mb_strlen` if you have non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

You need `mb_strlen()` for Unicode characters: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php

On the other hand if you're just counting how many entries in the database have more than 1000 characters, you can save some computing power with the MySQL function `CHAR_LENGTH()` to count the total in the database: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length

Answer (score 0):

You could let mysql do the counting as it knows the charset, has a counting function and can even give you the number of fields in a table that have more then 1000 characters directly:

```
SELECT count(*) as var FROM table WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(field) > 1000;
```

This will return your `var` as mysql result. This will spare you to return the whole table data just to obtain this number.